# Wrong sorting for Biber with Norwegian sortlocale

Tags: sorting, biber

There is a problem with the sorting for Biber when using `sortlocale=nb_NO`.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
  @misc{a,author = {A}} @misc{b,author = {B}} @misc{c,author = {C}}
  @misc{d,author = {D}} @misc{e,author = {E}} @misc{f,author = {F}}
  @misc{g,author = {G}} @misc{h,author = {H}} @misc{i,author = {I}}
  @misc{j,author = {J}} @misc{k,author = {K}} @misc{l,author = {L}}
  @misc{m,author = {M}} @misc{n,author = {N}} @misc{o,author = {O}}
  @misc{p,author = {P}} @misc{q,author = {Q}} @misc{r,author = {R}}
  @misc{s,author = {S}} @misc{t,author = {T}} @misc{u,author = {U}}
  @misc{v,author = {V}} @misc{w,author = {W}} @misc{x,author = {X}}
  @misc{y,author = {Y}} @misc{z,author = {Z}} @misc{ae,author = {Æ}}
  @misc{oe,author = {Ø}} @misc{aa,author = {Å}}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,sortlocale=nb_NO]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Compiling this file gives this result:

[image]

The letters Æ, Ø and Å should be last.

It seems this question looks too much like a bug report. I was kinda hoping for a workaround.

Comment: This looks like a bug report to me: have you logged it against Biber. (See http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2622 for how to handle such items.)

Comment: What platform are you on? It works fine for me on OSX.

Comment: @PLK I get the same with TeXlive 2012 on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Which Biber version?

Comment: @JosephWright  `biber -v` gives *biber version: 1.0*.

Comment: @PLK Ubuntu 12.04, TeX Live 2012, Biber 1.0.

Comment: This seems to be an issue only with the binary version. Running it as an unpacked perl program works fine on Linux. Looking into it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was indeed a bug in the packaging of the linux binary. I was packing slightly older DUCET 6.0 tailorings by mistake. Please get biber 1.1 from SF - it should be fixed in this build. You will also need biblatex 2.1 which is also on SF now.